# Class#newInstance in GWT

Tags: gwt

I know that GWT doesn't emulate this method, but I need smth that provide its functionality.
I have tried next approach:

```
    private static <T extends Widget> T createWidget(Class<T> widgetClass) {
        return GWT.create(widgetClass);
    }
```

But when I try to compile it I get an error:
**Only class literals may be used as arguments to GWT.create()**

So, how can I write a foresaid method that will emulate `Class#newInstance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GWT.create()` always needs the class literal as argument, which means that you has to pass this: `GWT.create(MyClass.class)` and no other thing.

This is so because the gwt compiler has to decide which class to pick up in compile time, note that in your code the class is passed in runtime.

If you are planing to use `GWT.create` for a reduced and well known set of classes you can do something like that:

```java
private static <T extends Widget> T createWidget(Class<T> widgetClass) {
    if (ClassA.class.equals(widgetClass))  {
       return GWT.create(ClassA.class);
    } else if (ClassA.class.equals(widgetClass))  {
       return GWT.create(ClassB.class);
    }
    return null;
}
```